# sudo graphical prompt

Tags: passwords, sudo, prompt

I have a script that must execute a command with root privileges, however I want the script to prompt for the sudo password in a graphical window, not in the terminal. Is this possible?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try gksu if you use gnome in any Linux flavor.